# Word count java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, return

So my code is supposed to return the amount of words (words being lengths of letters) and it works except for when i enter anything 0 or less can some pplease help spot the error??

Edited Code:

```
public class WordCount {
    public static int countWords(String original, int minLength){

        String[] s1 = original.split("\\s+");

        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
            s1[i] = s1[i].replaceAll("^\\W]", "");
        }


        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
            String str = s1[i];
            int len = 0;
            for(int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++){
                char c = str.charAt(x);

                if(Character.isLetter(c) == true){
                    len ++;
                }
            }
            if(len >= minLength){
                count ++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("enter string: ");
        String s = IO.readString();

        System.out.println("min length: ");
        int m = IO.readInt();

        System.out.println(countWords(s, m));


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the failure?. Can you post the exception trace or detailed information on what the failure is.

Comment: please be clear what was error you are getting and what is case

Comment: I edited the code a bit but if i type in the string "hey.. .. john." i receive 3 instead 2 because the is only 2 words.

Comment: @Newb18 that's something completely different than what your question is about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply a solution that uses a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to process the text.

I prepared a sketch of code, which can be summarized as follows:

```
String[] words = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", " ").split("\\s+");
```

What this code does is to:

- replace whatever is not a letter (since you said just letters) with a space
- split the results on the spaces

The resulting array `words` contains all the words (i.e., sequences of letters) which were contained in the original string.

A full example can be found [here](https://ideone.com/v3QwDy). In this example I just print the words as a list. In case you want just the count of words, you just have to return the count of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this :

```
 String s = original.replaceAll("[\\W]", " ").replaceAll("[\\s]+", " ");
```

because you have to replace spaces more than 1 here as well.